# UnsatisfiedDependencyException autowired on constructor and set not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I created a custom repository. In this repository, i need to access some method of standard repository (findAll), so I added

I used spring boot

```
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {UserAgendaApplication.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class})
@SpringBootApplication
public class UserAgendaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(UserAgendaApplication.class, args);
    }
}


public interface UsersRepositoryCustom {
    public Page<Users> customSearch(UserSearch UserSearch, Pageable page);
}



public interface UsersRepository extends JpaRepository<Users, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Users>, UsersRepositoryCustom {

}


@Repository
public class UsersRepositoryImpl implements UsersRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    private final UsersRepository usersRepository;

   @Autowired
   public UsersRepositoryImpl(final UsersRepository usersRepository){
        this.usersRepository=usersRepository;
   }

   @Override
   public Page<Users> customSearch(UserSearch UserSearch, Pageable page) {
         ...
         return usersRepository.findAll(specification, page);

   }

}

@Service
public class UsersServiceImpl implements UsersService {

    @Autowired
    public UsersServiceImpl(UsersRepository usersRepository) {
        this.usersRepository = usersRepository;
    }

    private UsersRepository usersRepository;

    @Override
public Page<Users> customSearch(UserSearch userSearch, Pageable page) {
   usersRepository.customSearch(userSearch, page);
    ... 
}

}
```

In a controller for a

```
@Controller
public class UsersController {

     private final UsersService usersService;

    @Autowired
    public UsersController( final usersService usersService){
        this.usersService=usersService;
    }

}
```

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'usersController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'usersService';
>   nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'usersServiceImpl' defined in file
>   [/home/alpha/Development/project/UserAgenda/build/classes/main/com/alpha/userAgenda/service/UsersServiceImpl.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
>   Error creating bean with name 'usersRepositoryImpl': Bean with name
>   'usersRepositoryImpl' has been injected into other beans
>   [usersRepository] in its raw version as part of a circular reference,
>   but has eventually been wrapped.  This means that said other beans do
>   not use the final version of the bean. This is often the result of
>   over-eager type matching - consider using 'getBeanNamesOfType' with
>   the 'allowEagerInit' flag turned off, for example.

I tried to put a autowired on setUsersRepository in the controller and UsersRepositoryImpl but get the same error

Edit

```
public abstract class UsersRepositoryCustom extends SimpleJpaRepository<Users, Integer>

public Page<Users> customSearch(UserSearch userSearch, Pageable page) {
...
}
```

Because i use SimpleJpaRepository, I don't need anymore UserRepository, but i need to add in UersRepositoryCustom this code

```
private final EntityManager entityManager;
private final JpaEntityInformation<Users, Integer> entityInformation;

@Autowired
public UsersRepositoryCustom(final JpaEntityInformation<Users, Integer> entityInformation,
        final EntityManager entityManager) {
    super(entityInformation, entityManager);
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
    this.entityInformation = entityInformation;
}
```

In my UsersServiceImpl who implement UsersService, i have

```
@Autowired
public UsersRepositoryCustom usersRepositoryCustom;
```

I get

Parameter 0 of constructor in .UsersRepositoryImpl required a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation' that could not be found.

Edit 2

gradle config

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

mainClassName = 'com.alpha.useragenda.UserAgendaApplication'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

    compile group: 'org.hsqldb', name: 'hsqldb', version: '2.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.1.1'

    compile group: 'org.webjars', name: 'bootstrap', version: '3.3.7'
    compile group: 'org.webjars.bower', name: 'bootstrap-table', version: '1.11.1'
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs = ["-Xlint:unchecked", "-Xlint:deprecation", "-parameters"]
}
```

Comment: That is never going to work. To create `UserRepository` you need an instance of your custom implementation, but that custom implementation needs the `UserRepository`. You have a dependency in a bean on itself... What is so special about the `customSearch` method that you need a special implementation instead of a regular `findAll`?

Comment: there is surely a way to access repository method when you use a custom repository

Comment: Not without creating a circulair dependency from the point of Spring Data. So currently there isn't. As mentioned what is so special about that `customSearch` method that you need a custom implementation...

Comment: if you need to create a custom query, not with @Query annotation, you need to create you own repository with your methotd...

Comment: You could add an abstract class, move the customSearch method to it, have it implementing  UsersRepository interface. This way you would have an abstract interface in the code calling the repo and no circular dependency. Just a thought

Comment: I know why and how to create a custom implementation (trust me on that). I only wonder if you really need a custom repository in this case, I suspect it should actually go into the service and not the repository.

Comment: I still do not se why UsersRepository and UsersRepositoryImpl need to implement UsersRepositoryCustom. To me UsersRepository impmantring UsersReposiotryCustom is not necessary since it is in UsersRespositoryImpl. This might get you out of the circular dependency. I can't verify this idea now

Comment: You need to break the circular dependency. First I would try eliminating from UsersRepository "implements UsersRepositoryCustom" The custom method is implemented in UsersCustomImpl. It does not need to be anywhere else.

Comment: @efekctive, hum how i will access to my custom method in my service layer if it's not in a interface?

Comment: You auto wire the service with an abstract class that implements the repo but has the custom method. No circular dependency and you get an abstract type, it does not need to be always an interface, in your service for loose coupling. You may end up with an extra method call: service->Abstract->Repo but if the custom call is vital you got it

Comment: If you post the pom, I could tinker with this

Comment: don't use maven, i use gradle, don't think that have something to do with that

Comment: I know. It was a way to set a project up quickly here. If I get around to it and if I get it to work, I will post the answer

Answer (score 0):

I think your best shot is to use this

```
package stack.overflow;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UsersCrud extends CrudRepository<Users, Long> {

    //My other query prototypes here

    @Query("select c1 from t1")
    public Object customQuery();
}
```

This way you get the special query with minimal effort. Otherwise I suggest to follow the advice given in the OP comments (leave repository alone and deal with special case in service